# Django: make user is_active = False

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a user model and a template with list of user with buttons DISABLE user, by clicking on which profile becomes inactive.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    some user fields

    def block_profile(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user = self.user
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Profile successfully disabled.')
        return redirect('index')
```

**views.py**

```
def user_list(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()        
    return render(request, "vstories/vstories.html", {'profiles':profiles})
```

**vstories.html**

```
{% for profile in profiles %}   
    {{ profile.nickname }}
    <button> ??BLOCK_USER?? </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Did I write the function correctly in the model and how do I insert it in the template to output the button?

Comment: better if you write functionality changes in views.py instead of models.py

Comment: in which case I will need to make an additional url and template, or can I do without it?

Comment: Is it possible make new status in same page without new page redirect?

Comment: yes you have to create a new url and you can use ajax call for same to avoid refresh

Comment: Ok, I try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply add a model's method to a template, you need to write a view for that. You can use POST method to catch the id of profile that you want to deactivate:

**views.py**

```
def user_list(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()        
    return render(request, "vstories/vstories.html", {'profiles':profiles})

def deactivate_user():
    if request.method==POST:
        pk = request.POST.get('pk')
        profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        profile.block_profile()
```

You will also need to add some url for this view in your **urls.py**

And then in your template, you can use a simple html form with a hidden input for id of each profile.
**vstories.html**

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
    <form action="/url_of_your_deactivate_view/" method="post">
      {{ profile.nickname }}
      <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{ profile.pk }}">
      <input type="submit" value="Deactivate user">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, I think that your block_profile method should be inside of Profile model instead of User model.

Comment: I got Error 'Profile' object has no attribute 'deactivate'

Comment: I called method deactivate () just as an example. In your case it is called block_profile(). And you should move this method to your Profile model as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check block_profile() in views.py

Comment: it works, and most importantly that it works without going to another url!! Thanks!